# Lexing "1 -1". How does a lexer decide its 1 - 1 instead of just two numbers next to each other?

Tags: compiler-construction, theory

I'm new to writing compilers, and I want to know the proper solution to this problem. Currently if there is the possibility of two different tokens I chose the one that is longer - it works, but I want to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works"?  Wouldn't choosing the longer token mean it *wouldn't* treat "1 - 1" as 3 short tokens instead of 2 longer ones?

Comment: Some languages solve this by not having denotations for negative numbers.  So `-1` is unary operator minus followed by integer 1.  You're then left with the problem of distinguishing binary minus from unary minus, which can presumably be done in compilation.  And "unary minus, integer one" can often be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: You can skip the lexing altogether - if your language allows in different context both a binary operation `1 - 1` and a space-separated sequence of numbers `1 -1`, you'll parse them differently depending on the context. Use PEG/Packrat, for example, or a GLR, and skip the lexing pass altogether. Lexerless parsing is superior in far too many ways to have a dedicated lexer in the 21st century.